# .NET Core MVC form passing model with null properties

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form that is suppose to pass my `Encounter` model to my `CharacterController`'s `CreateCharacter` action method.

Here is the form:

```
<form asp-action="CreateCharacter" asp-controller="Character" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#character-container">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Create Chracter</button>
</form>
```

Here's the controller method:

```
public ActionResult CreateCharacter(Encounter encounter)
{
    Character character = new Character { Encounter = encounter };
    return PartialView("Add", character);
}
```

All the properties of `encounter` are null when they shouldn't be. To clarify, `Encounter` is the model for the view that the form is in. Within this view, I use the `Name` property of `Encounter` and it works fine. When I pass the model to my controller, however, the `Name` property is now null.

I'm confused why this is happening because I have a very similar form elsewhere that passes a model fine.

Comment: How is that form populating the model? There are no input fields. What fields are the form suppose to populate?

Comment: I'm using the form as a work around to send the model to the controller when the button is clicked. Could that be my problem?

Comment: But there is nothing to send. That form only has a submit button. It is not sending any data as there are no input fields to represent the data to be sent. If it sends nothing then the action will get a null value.

Comment: That makes sense. I've added hidden inputs now to pass the properties. Thank you. If you don't mind me asking, is using the form to pass a model to a controller best practice?

Comment: It is usually how they get submitted to the contoller.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No data is being submitted to the controller.

That form only has a submit button.

It is not sending any data as there are no input fields to represent the model to be sent.

If it sends nothing then the action will get a null value.

Ensure that there are values to be sent that match the properties on the model to be sent.

```
<form asp-action="CreateCharacter" asp-controller="Character" data-ajax="true" 
        data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#character-container">

    <input type="hidden" name="propertyName" value="propertyValue">

    <!--
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    -->     

    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Create Chracter</button>
</form>
```